# Managing encapsulated data in closure

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

Newbie here.Using Google API Nearby Search. I have problem sending encapsulated data into closure, already populated table with vicinity info, but when i try to send placeID info into closure to get Details, it gives me nil.

Here i get placeID and vicinity, and afterwards populate tableView with places array. Class Place is in separate swift file, function downloadPlaceID is inside ViewController.

```
 class Place {

    var placeId: String!
    var vicinity: String!

    var _placeId: String {
        if placeId == nil {
            placeId = ""
        }
        return placeId
    }

    var _vicinity: String {
        if vicinity == nil {
            vicinity = ""
        }
        return vicinity
    }


    init( place: [String:Any]) {

        if let ids = place["id"] as? String {
            self.placeId = ids

        }

        if let vicinities = place["vicinity"] as? String {
            self.vicinity = vicinities

        }

    }

}


func downloadPlaceID (completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {

        let placeURL = URL(string: nearbyURL)

        Alamofire.request(placeURL!).responseJSON { (response) in
            let result = response.result

            if let dictionary = result.value as? [String:Any] {
                if let results = dictionary["results"] as? [[String:Any]] {

                    if let status = dictionary["status"] as? String  {
                        if status == "OK" {
                            for obj in results {
                                place = Place(place: obj)
                                // here i get all the placeID's
                                places.append(place)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            completed()
        }
    }
```

Then i try to get details, into which I put placeID:

```
   func downloadDetails( input: String, completed: DownloadComplete) {

        let details = "\(detailsBaseURL)\(detailsPlaceId)\(input)\(detailsKey)\(detailsSearchAPIKey)"
        print(placeID)

        Alamofire.request(details).responseJSON { response in
            let result = response.result

            if let dictionary = result.value as? [String:Any] {

                if let result = dictionary["result"] as? [String:Any] {

                    if let phoneNumber = result["formatted_phone_number"] as? String {
                        self.phone = phoneNumber
                        print(self.phone!)
                    }

                    if let  geometry = result["geometry"] as? [String:Any] {
                        if let location = geometry["location"] as? [String:Any] {
                            if let latitude = location["lat"] as? Double {
                                self.lat = latitude
                                print(self.lat!)
                            }
                            if let longitude = location["lng"] as? Double {
                                self.lng = longitude
                                print(self.lng!)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if let openingHours = result["opening_hours"] as? [String:Any] {
                        if let openNow = openingHours["open_now"] as? Bool {
                            self.workHours = openNow
                             print(self.workHours!)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is code inside viewDidLoad that i'm trying to use to get details.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


downloadPlaceID {
    detail.downloadDetails(input: place.placeId, completed: {

    })
}



}
```

Comment: You have 6 conditions that can fail: placeURL can be wrongly created, the request could fail, and some variable could be nil (dictionary, results, status). Put a breakdown at the top and debug line by line to check which one is failing, it will help you and us understanding the problem.

Comment: Please put actual code. The last fragment isn't even valid Swift. The middle fragment is a function with just comments in it. The first fragment isn't called anywhere.

Comment: @JeremyP - I put actual code. I can't get place.placeID outside downloadPlaceID func. When i put random placeID, i receive all the details(phone, addresses, etc.), if i try to put place.placeID it gives me nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be "place_id" instead of "id"

```
  class Place {

        var placeId: String!
        var vicinity: String!

        var _placeId: String {
            if placeId == nil {
                placeId = ""
            }
            return placeId
        }

        var _vicinity: String {
            if vicinity == nil {
                vicinity = ""
            }
            return vicinity
        }


        init( place: [String:Any]) {

            if let ids = place["place_id"] as? String {
                self.placeId = ids

            }

            if let vicinities = place["vicinity"] as? String {
                self.vicinity = vicinities

            }

        }

    }
```